# I am failing to get the modal pop up in bootstrap 3

Tags: bootstrap-modal

This the code i wrote. I have checked queries related to this, on other platforms and forums, the similar coding is working but not for me

```
<div style="text-align: center; width: 100%">
    <button style="position: absolute; top: 50%" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">SUBSCRIBE</button>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- modal header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <!-- modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <!-- modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The same code i posted is working on jsfiddle.
Modal does not popup in chrome or any other browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you include the bootstrap.js? (preferably at the end of the body)

Comment: Are you referring to this?
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: For better results at least in developing mode, download the source and include it to your project. So I am suggesting download bootstrap from official page and include the bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js file before the closing body tag </body>

Comment: After adding the bootstrap.js before closing the body tag it worked.
I wonder why it did not work while bootstrap.js was in the head tag?

Comment: I don't know exactly the reason, so I will let some else to answer, but as a general rule you put js at the end

Answer (score 0):

Here is it working.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div style="text-align: center; width: 100%">
  <button style="position: absolute; top: 50%" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">SUBSCRIBE</button>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!-- modal header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <!-- modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!-- modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```